# Firefox browser: threads of same process OR different process

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

Today i was reading about `thread` vs `process`.
I am really confused about its examples.

Lets say we are executing `Firefox` browser.It contains fer tabs. Now, when a new tab is opened, the `Is it called the thread of the same process?`

Now, a user invokes another copy of the `Firefox`. Lets say one copy of the browser has 5 tabs & the other[`new copy`]  has 3 tabs. **Whether they will be called as threads of the same process or considered by the `OS` as different processes?**

I opened the `task manager`[`Windows XP`] & found that it shows only one instance of `Firefox`.
Please clarify **What does it mean?**

Comment: Have a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/191865/does-firefox-create-a-new-thread-per-tab-thread-per-instance. AFAIK there is no clear relation between tabs and threads spawned by Firefox. We can only say for sure that the plugin container and the flash plugin are run in a separate process such that they don't bring the entire browser down in case of a crash.

Comment: Open Task Manager and, In the 'Process' pane, ensure that the 'Threads' column is selected.  Oen Firefox, check its threads.  Open some tabs, check again.  I have four tabs open and TM shows 31 threads for Firefox.